# jetstream inertia открывает ссылки в модальном окне

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertia

Я скопировал из какого-то гит репозитория проект jetstream-inertia, только на react. В нём все компоненты переписаны с vue на react. И здесь все ссылки (`Link` и `InertiaLink` из `inertia-react) открываются в модальном окне. Если через консоль посмотреть, то это iframe[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я не понимаю, откуда берётся такое поведение.
Вот код:

```js
// app.tsx
import React from "react";
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import {createInertiaApp} from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";

import Layout from "@/Layouts/Layout";
import {IPage} from "@/types/iPage";

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name: string) => {
        const page = require(`./Pages/${name}`).default;

        // Add default layout for all components
        (page as IPage).layout =
            page.layout || ((page) => <Layout children={page}/>);

        return page;
    },
    setup({el, App, props}) {
        const root = createRoot(el);
        root.render(<App {...props} />);
    },

});
```

```js
// hooks/useRoute
import route, {Config, RouteParam, RouteParamsWithQueryOverload} from "ziggy-js";
import {Ziggy} from "@/ziggy";

const useRoute = () => {
    return (
        name?: string,
        params?: RouteParamsWithQueryOverload | RouteParam,
        absolute?: boolean,
        config: any = Ziggy
    ) => route(name, params, absolute, config);
}

export default useRoute;

// Layouts/Layout.tsx
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Inertia} from "@inertiajs/inertia";
import {Link, InertiaLink} from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";
import useRoute from "@/hooks/useRoute";

const Layout: React.FC<any> = (props) => {
    const route = useRoute();
    
    return (
        <div>
            <header>
                <InertiaLink href={route('home')}>Home</InertiaLink>
                <InertiaLink href={route('dashboard')}>Dashboard</InertiaLink>
                <InertiaLink href={route('myPage')}>My page</InertiaLink>
            </header>
            <main>
                {props.children}
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

```js
// Pages/MyPage.tsx
import React from "react";
import {IPage} from "@/types/IPage";

const MyPage: IPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
           My Page
        </div>
    );
}

export default MyPage;
```

Я посмотрел примеры сайтов на inertiaJS - https://laracasts.com/ - здесь тоже ссылки открываются в iframe. Это очень странно.

Пока единственное решение, которое я нашел, это добавлять атрибут `as="button"` для `InertiaLink`:

```js
export default function CLink({
    href,
    children,
    className
}: PropsWithChildren<Props>) {
    return (
        <InertiaLink href={href} className={className} >
            {children}
        </InertiaLink>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

По идее, дело не во фронте, а в бэке. Эндпоинты (роуты, методы контроллеров), на которые ссылаются `InertialLink` должны отдавать `Inertia::render`.

Comment: И в роутах, и в контроллерах я возвращаю `return Inertia:render('')`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-jetstream-react - я использовал этот пакет для создания inertia приложения. Но всё равно из коробки оно открывает ссылки в новом окне

Comment: ахахпа, я поискал примеры сайтов на inertiaJS - https://laracasts.com/ Даже на ларакасте ссылки так открываются